# Black Diamond Question Marks vs. Loss of Certain Characters

Tags: php, html, unicode, encoding

I have read up on this problem and encountered it before, but I have yet to find a solution to both sides of it.  I have a news aggregator that pulls in news from RSS feeds. Upon displaying the content I was getting black diamond question marks, so after doing some research, I added the following line of code (PHP):

```
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

This was successful at fixing that issue, but looking at another article that had some Spanish words with accents, I noticed the accents had been converted to funky characters.  They had looked fine before.  For example, now I see stuff like:

genÃ©ticas

Now I'd rather have the 2nd issue as it doesn't stick out as much, but ideally I want to fix both.  My MySQL tables are UTF-8, as well as the doctype of the page.  Any ideas??

Comment: Since you're aggregating from different feeds, which all have their different encoding types, you need some form of conversion. If I remember correctly, all charsets can be converted to utf8 by some means, though it varies between each charset. Faved, I'd like to see the answer for this one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pulling your data in from more than one feed, therefore you can't depend on all the feeds you're pulling in having the same character encoding.

XML feeds are supposed to announce what charset they are in the XML preamble, and the server should send headers stating the character encoding the file is using, but they aren't necessarially present, and if they are they aren't certain to be accurate.

You can use [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) to try and figure out what encoding the file you're parsing uses, but again, that's not 100% certain to be accurate.

So if your goal is normalizing all feeds you're processing into the same charset (I'm guessing UTF 8), your options are to look at the XML preamble, the headers (if the appropriate one has been sent) and the result of mb_detect_encoding to determine the encoding. If all the above agree you probably (but don't certainly) have a good idea what encoding the file is in and what you need to do to convert it.  If there's a disagreement between any of these methods, then you'll have to decide for yourself what action to take.

In short, welcome to charset hell.  How do you like it?

Comment: By using mb_detect_encoding I was able to fix things up.  I said if the encoding is not UTF-8, then use mb_convert_encoding and convert the text, else just leave it alone. Thanks!